# Deserialize doctrine entity with JMS Serializer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have seen some questions related on S.O but somehow the answers don't solve my problem.

I'm using JMS Deserializer to serialize doctrine entity to store into a string. However, when I deserialize it, I run into the following issue:

The field **id** is set to readonly (because it's supposed to be auto-generated), and thus upon deserializing it does not get set back to the entity. Without the id, entityManager->merge does not work. The obvious solution is to add a setId method to the entity so that it is set back on deserialization process. However, that just doesn't feel right because id is not supposed to be set...

Comment: Did you "expose" the id?

Comment: It's supposed to be set, for example when you need to unserialize an entity, which happens to the issue here! I don't know if JMS Serializer uses reflection under to hood to set protected/private properties without a getter, but to me this seems worst than just putting a setter.

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer: yes I exposed the ID, but I set read-only to it as well

Comment: @AlbertoFernández: so you think I should add the setter method to the entity?

Comment: Could you add some code?  I guess it's something that happen when you saved an entity in a session? The question lack a little bit of details.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve I did not add that detail because it may distract from the real issue since I'm asking for this issue in general, not in any specific case. But you are exactly right, in my case I serialize entity, save in db/session and the deserialize back. My problem is that the deserialized entity is not attached to the real entity in db.   Right now I have to add the setId method to be able to set back the id into the deserialized object, then I use entityManager->merge and refresh the object.

Comment: @mr1031011 it might be the fact that you use the entityManager, it's deprecated. Just use the manager.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve I think the method getEntityManager was deprecated, but I'm using the service doctrine.orm.entity_manager. But I think it is not the point here. What I really wonder here is that obviously many people must have the need to serialize then deserialize an entity with jms bundle just like me. And when I did that, I ran into the problem when I have to merge back the entity. I solved it by adding the public method setId to the entity, which I feel wrong. I just wonder how you guys do it if there is any other way.

Comment: did you manage to make it work @mr1031011